# In Android SDK Manager packages are missing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I was using adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729 on windows 8 and everything was fine until I decided to upgrade and downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702. Now I cannot see any packages in SDK Manager:

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Delete and re-extract adt.
- Run SDK Manager as administrator.
- Disable antivirus and firewall (I'm not behind a proxy server).
- Check "Force https://..." in SDK Manager's settings.
- Check "Enable Preview Tools" in SDK Manager's settings.
- Check and Uncheck all of the checkboxes on SDK Manager.
- Clear SDK Manager's cache.
- Reload SDK Manager's packages.
- Start SDK manager from Eclipse.
- Download packages and copy them to sdk/temp folder.
- Run android.bat from command prompt.
- Add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to android.bat.
- Delete c:\Users\username\.android folder.

**UPDATE:**
I did a factory reset on my laptop with no luck.

Comment: Check if all your platform images are still located in this folder C:\Tools\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms

Comment: android-20 is in platforms folder.

Comment: @G3M The problem is when I want to create a new avd I get: No system images installed for this target, and I thought I could install the image in SDK Manager.

Comment: I am sorry! My bad.I get it now. I did have this problem once and it was resolved when i used force https.but I see that you have already tried that.